# Converting circular structure to JSON error while saving conversation state in cosmos DB in node js bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cosmosdb, azure-language-understanding

Error in luis flow while prompting.

1. Enter view pnr - luis finds the intent and followed by enter pnr number prompt followed by this error while saving state in `this.onDialog()`.

```js
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, false); 

const storage = new CosmosDbStorage({
                serviceEndpoint: cosmoConfigVal.serviceEndpoint,
                authKey: CosmosAuthKey,
                databaseId: cosmoConfigVal.databaseId,
                collectionId: cosmoConfigVal.statecollectionId
            });            
           const conversationState = new ConversationState(storage);
           const userState      = new UserState(storage);
```

---

```sh
[onTurnError] unhandled error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'DocumentClient'
    |     property '_globalEndpointManager' -> object with constructor 'Base.defineClass.getReadEndpoint'
    --- property 'client' closes the circle
(node:86632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR
```

Comment: Did you include 2-3 separate pieces of code, or are you re-creating both state and `CosmosDbStorage` multiple times? Can you either `console.log()` or set a breakpoint before saving state and paste the output of `context` before `conversationState` gets saved?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? I'm happy to help, but need that additional information.